# Why is an Action<T> not implicit convertable to Action<U> when T : U?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, action

Consider this code:

```
class BaseEvent {}
class DummyEvent : BaseEvent {}

void FooBase(BaseEvent e) {}
void FooDummy(DummyEvent e) {}

void main(String[] args) {
   Action<BaseEvent> actionBase = FooBase;
   Action<DummyEvent> actionDummy = FooDummy;

   // Works implicit
   Action<DummyEvent> actionDummy2 = actionBase;
   // Only explcit
   Action<BaseEvent> actionBase2 = (Action<BaseEvent>)actionDummy; 
}
```

I dont understand why it works like this, wouldn´t it make more sense the other way around considering how it works with object references?

```
void main(String[] args) {
   BaseEvent baseEvent = new BaseEvent();
   DummyEvent dummyEvent = new DummyEvent();

   // Works implicit
   BaseEvent baseEvent2 = dummyEvent;     
   // Only explicit
   DummyEvent dummyEvent2 = (DummyEvent)baseEvent2; 
}
```

I want to write code which stores a Map of Action and pass in diffrent Events like this:

```
class EventManager {
   Dicionary<int, Action<BaseEvent>> eventHandlers = new Dicionary<int, Action<BaseEvent>>();

   public void AddHandler(int eventType, Action<BaseEvent> eventHandler) {
      eventHandlers.Add(eventType, eventHandler);
   }
   public void TriggerEvent(BaseEvent e) {
      eventHandlers[e.EventType](e);
   }
}

void HandleDummyEvent(DummyEvent e) 
{
   // Some code
}

void main(String[] args) {
   EventManager eventManager = new EventManager();
   eventManager.AddHandler(DummyEvent.EventType, HandleDummyEvent);
   eventManager.TriggerEvent(new DummyEvent());
}
```

Comment: If all Bs are As, does it mean that all As are also Bs? This is not related to delegates at all, it simply the difference between downcasting and upcasting.

Comment: Do read about [Covariance and Contravariance in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It even has examples regarding `Action<T>`

Comment: Don't use `A` and `B`.  Use meaningful type names.  Then it will make far more sense.  If a method can accept only Tigers can you treat it as a method that can accept any Animal?  What happens if you pass a Bear to that method after such a conversion?

Comment: Using `Animal` and `Tiger : Animal`, I think an action involving a tiger (`Action<Tiger>`) can be an action involving an animal (`Action<Animal>`), because an action involving a generic animal would work with a tiger as well, but an action involving a tiger doesn't necessarily work with all animals. With types, a tiger is an animal, but an animal isn't necessarily a tiger.

Comment: @PrinceTyke So if you wrote a method that accepts a `Tiger`, and it, say, uses the tiger's `CountStripes` method to print the number of stripes that are on the tiger, what do you think should happen if, after casting that method to an `Action<Animal>` you pass in a `Bear`, that has no idea how to count its own stripes?  An `Action<Animal>` represents a method *that can accept any `Animal`*.  You can pass a `Tiger` to a method that has a parameter of type `Animal`, but you can't pass any `Animal` to a method that accepts a `Tiger`.

Comment: @Servy I'll admit, I'm somewhat new to C#, so I don't know how it handles its generics, but that's what I meant with my second statement. In my mind, `CountStripes(Tiger)` is different than `List<Tiger>`. You can put a `Tiger` in a `List<Animal>` but you can't put an `Animal` in a `List<Tiger>`. Maybe I'm wrong, or maybe I'm completely missing the point of the question or the concept of generics.

Comment: @PrinceTyke So your `List<Animal>` has an `Add` method.  It accepts an `Animal`.  It could be stored in an `Action<Animal>`.  Your `Action<Animal>` can accept a `Tiger`, so you could *pretend* that it was an `Action<Tiger>` because all tigers are valid parameters to the method.  If you have a `List<Tiger>` the `Add` method is an `Action<Tiger>`.  That method cannot accept any `Animal`, which is what you're saying it can do if you want to treat it as an `Action<Animal>`.

Comment: @Servy Okay, what you're saying all makes sense, but I'm still confused. The top answer on the duplicate question mentions this
"The type parameter of `Action` is contravariant: you can assign an `Action<object>` to an `Action<string>` because obviously a
method that can work on any object can also work on a string." -Jon
(Edit: formatting is hard)